# PHP json_decode array unable to get sub array

Tags: php, json

I'm getting a json response and have converted into array using json_decode.

var_dump gives the following:

```
array(1) {
  ["FlightInfoResult"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["next_offset"]=>
    int(1)
    ["flights"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(19) {
        ["ident"]=>
        string(6) "AXB443"
        ["aircrafttype"]=>
        string(4) "B738"
        ["filed_ete"]=>
        string(8) "03:10:00"
        ["filed_time"]=>
        int(1498358100)
        ["filed_departuretime"]=>
        int(1498530900)
        ["filed_airspeed_kts"]=>
        int(376)
        ["filed_airspeed_mach"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["filed_altitude"]=>
        int(0)
        ["route"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["actualdeparturetime"]=>
        int(0)
        ["estimatedarrivaltime"]=>
        int(1498542900)
        ["actualarrivaltime"]=>
        int(0)
        ["diverted"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["origin"]=>
        string(4) "VOCI"
        ["destination"]=>
        string(4) "OOMS"
        ["originName"]=>
        string(26) "Cochin Int'l (Kochi Int'l)"
        ["originCity"]=>
        string(20) "Kochi / Nedumbassery"
        ["destinationName"]=>
        string(10) "Seeb Int'l"
        ["destinationCity"]=>
        string(6) "Muscat"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to get the contents that comes within flights, ident:AXB443, etc..
I am not able to print any elements of the array.

Comment: use `$variable['FlightInfoResult']['flights'][0]['ident']`

Comment: try using `print_r()`, it'll be much clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is multidimensional array. After json_decode you can get it via `$variable['FlightInfoResult']['flights'][0]['ident']`;

An variant on `var_dump()` is `print_r()`. This will give a simpeler, but in this case better to understand output.

Comment: Thanks ! That helped. I missed the [0]